# How do you get the output of a system command in Go?

Tags: go

Let's say I want to run 'ls' in a go program, and store the results in a string. There seems to be a few commands to fork processes in the exec and os packages, but they require file arguments for stdout, etc. Is there a way to get the output as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer is obsolete. Please see [Fatih Arslan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15815730/27358) below.

---

Use [exec.Run](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/#Cmd.Run) by specifying [Pipe](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/#Constants) as the stdout (and stderr if you want). It will return cmd, which contains an [os.File](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) in the Stdout (and Stderr) fields. Then you can read it using for example [ioutil.ReadAll](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll).

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "exec";
    "io/ioutil";
)

func main() {
    if cmd, e := exec.Run("/bin/ls", nil, nil, exec.DevNull, exec.Pipe, exec.MergeWithStdout); e == nil {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(cmd.Stdout)
        println("output: " + string(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the "exec" package exists anymore. I had to use "os/exec" as listed by Fatih below.

Comment: Downvote reason: This answer probably is outdated, and wanted people to know about it. `exec` package no longer exists afaik, `ioutil.ReadAll()` no longer accepts `cmd.Stdout` but `cmd.Stdin`, thus almost everything about this answer is wrong and outdated.

Answer (score 444):

There is an easier way now:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)
}
```

Where `out` is the standard output. It's in the format `[]byte`, but you can change it to string easily with:

```
string(out)
```

You can also use `CombinedOutput()`  instead of `Output()` which returns standard output and standard error.

[exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

Comment: This should most likely be the accepted answer now. The accepted answer doesn't even compile anymore.

Comment: Useful if you don't need to do anything else with the command (add environment variables, for example).

Comment: A go playground with this code: https://play.golang.org/p/QM4JcIPrxJB

Answer (score 67):

To get both stdout and stderr into separate strings, you can use byte buffers like so:

```
cmd := exec.Command("date")
var outb, errb bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &outb
cmd.Stderr = &errb
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println("out:", outb.String(), "err:", errb.String())
```

Answer (score 17):

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-al")
output, _ := cmd.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

or

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(name, arg...)
stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout
if err != nil {
    return err
}
if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    return err
}
for {
    tmp := make([]byte, 1024)
    _, err := stdout.Read(tmp)
    fmt.Print(string(tmp))
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: For an interactive command that I needed to run and read all the output from several times. An interactive command I was running. This helped to see the output, where io.ReadAll did not for reasons unknown to me

Comment: Careful! I just learned (using Go 1.19) if you call `stdout.Read(tmp)` and there is nothing else to read, then it will block. This hit me up for a few hours (sad panda).

Answer (score 6):

I used this with a recent version of GO (~1.11)

```
// CmdExec Execute a command
func CmdExec(args ...string) (string, error) {

    baseCmd := args[0]
    cmdArgs := args[1:]

    log.Debugf("Exec: %v", args)

    cmd := exec.Command(baseCmd, cmdArgs...)
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return string(out), nil
}

// Usage:
// out, err := CmdExec("ls", "/home")
```

Answer (score 4):

Two options, depending on the paradigm you prefer:

1. [os.ForkExec()](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#ForkExec)
2. [exec.Run()](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/#Cmd.Run)

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting `string` output, `strings.Builder` is more efficient [1] than
`bytes.Buffer`:

```
package main

import (
   "os/exec"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   c, b := exec.Command("go", "version"), new(strings.Builder)
   c.Stdout = b
   c.Run()
   print(b.String())
}
```

1. https://golang.org/pkg/bytes#Buffer.String

Answer (score 3):

Use [exec.Run](http://golang.org/pkg/exec/#Cmd.Run), passing Pipe for stdout.  Read from the pipe that it returns.

Comment: That should probably be referred to as exec.Run() (which returns a Cmd), rather than Cmd.Run.