# Reading Stdout from a subprocess

Tags: go

I am attempting to spawn a subprocess from Golang. The goal is to read and process the input line-by-line. Here is what I am trying to get working:

```
func readStuff(scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Performed Scan")
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous", "-inmic", "yes")
    out, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    err = cmd.Start()
    checkError(err)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out)
    fmt.Println("Scanner created")

    defer cmd.Wait()
    go readStuff(scanner)
}
```

In this example, "Scanner created" is printed, but nothing happens after that.

Running this command however does result in what I am expecting to be printed to :

```
/usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes 1>out.txt
```

And modifying the code to directly copy to `stdout` works as well:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/local/bin/pocketsphinx_continuous", "-inmic", "yes")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
```

What am I missing that is keeping me from reading the output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the output of a system command in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877045/how-do-you-get-the-output-of-a-system-command-in-go)

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple things you may want to check.

1. The error code returned by `cmd.StdoutPipe()` is not checked. It should be.
2. The `pocketsphinx_continuous` command requires the `-hmm` and `-dict` arguments to be provided. Otherwise, it will fail, and all the output is actually sent to `stderr` and not `stdout`. Here, you read only `stdout`, but there is nothing to read.
3. You should not call `cmd.Wait()` before being sure all the data have been read from `stdout`. The result is non deterministic (actually, it is a race condition). Check the documentation about the `os/exec` package. If you absolutely need the parsing to be done in a goroutine, you need to synchronize with the end of the goroutine before `cmd.Wait()` is called. For instance, you could write the function as:

   ```
   func readStuff(scanner *bufio.Scanner, stop chan bool) {
       // Scanning code
       // ...
       stop<-true
   }
   ```

   and the main code as:

   ```
   stop := make(chan bool)
   go readStuff(scanner,stop)
   <-stop
   cmd.Wait()
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I updated my code to check that error, and not call wait before reading all the lines. I am still only seeing lines from StdErr. (PocketSphinx will still work without those arguments, it just has poor recognition) http://hastebin.com/ojetacoraw.go

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need not

```
go readStuff(scanner)
```

because of

```
cmd.Start()
```

do system fork itself
so just

```
readStuff(scanner)
```

would be enough to my mind
(not spawning gorouting for that)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine, and it works with `go readStuff(scanner)` and also with just `readStuff(scanner)` - I don't think that this usage actually calls for a goroutine, but don't know the actual context.:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func readStuff(scanner *bufio.Scanner) {
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Performed Scan")
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/Users/rfay/bin/junk.sh")
    out, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Failed to start err=%v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(out)
    fmt.Println("Scanner created")

    defer cmd.Wait()

    go readStuff(scanner)
}
```

This is the junk.sh I used for testing.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
  echo $i
  sleep 1
done
```