# How to capture/log everything after spawning an interactive program

Tags: go

I have a method that can spawn an interactive process, now how do I log everything (including stdin and stdout) after spawning ?

e.g.,

```
func execute(cmd1 string, slice []string) {

    cmd := exec.Command(cmd1, slice...)

    // redirect the output to terminal
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin

    cmd.Run()
}
```

..
The interactive program could be :
execute(ftp)

I think I have to dup stdin, stdout and read write in separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than redirecting it's output to the terminal read it and then you can log/print do whatever you want with it.

```
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(stdout)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Something like the code above would work though there are many options. I think you'll want to remove all that code you have to redirect to the terminal.

Comment: cannot use cmd.Stdout (type io.Writer) as type io.Reader in argument to ioutil.ReadAll:
 io.Writer does not implement io.Reader (missing Read method)

Comment: i used your statement before and after run both times same error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was looking at an example with some different settings supplied to `Run`. Try making that `cmd.StdoutPipe()` instead https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdoutPipe - I updated the example to more closely reflect whats in the docs there. You may still need some other changes to your programs control flow for it to function well.

Comment: @Victor also check out this answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877045/how-do-you-get-the-output-of-a-system-command-in-go if you call an overload of run you can reduce your code quite a bit.

Comment: isnt run a blocking call ? readall is also blocking so should i run readall in separate thread ?

Answer (score 0):

you could store the output in a temporary buffer and write it to several places

```
outBuf := bytes.Buffer{}
cmd := exec.Command(cmd1, slice...)

cmd.Stdout = &outBuf

cmd.Run()

if outBuf.Len() > 0 {
    log.Printf("%s", outBuf.String())
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s", outBuf.String())
}
```

Comment: good idea, but if the program is interactive such as ftp, then it wont print until the run command exits. e.g., if cmd1 is 'ftp'