# Filtering the output of a terminal output using golang

Tags: shell, go

A simple execution of go command gives some output as given here: [How do you get the output of a system command in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877045/how-do-you-get-the-output-of-a-system-command-in-go)?
But the code I am using is for showing the output with progress from : https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/wOYk/advanced-command-execution-in-go-with-osexec.html?
Now, I can't actually filter the output that I am getting from this as I don't want everything to be printed and only a part of it. Is there a way to do so?

I have already tried implementing a string to get the output instead of go routine way. But it didn't work. I want the progress too.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

The sample you're pointing to reads from the subprocess's stdout, and for each read it writes what it read to its own stdout while also capturing it:

```
func copyAndCapture(w io.Writer, r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    var out []byte
    buf := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf[:])
        if n > 0 {
            d := buf[:n]
            out = append(out, d...)
            _, err := w.Write(d)
            if err != nil {
                return out, err
            }
        }
        if err != nil {
            // Read returns io.EOF at the end of file, which is not an error for us
            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil
            }
            return out, err
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called with `os.Stdout` as `w`.

Now, you're free to filter the data `d` before you print it out with `w.Write`.