# I ran scp -i ssh "<filepath of remote linux machine> . " using Go from my client machine, but it is returning "no such file or directory"

Tags: go, scp

How to execute the scp -i ssh " . " using Go?

I have used the following code snippet.

```
cmd := exec.Command("scp -i dragonstone.pem <user>@ubuntu:<file location> .")
err = cmd.Run()
```

Comment: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15815730/1218512)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact error message that you're getting from scp. Don't paraphrase it. And what happens when you run that scp command interactively, instead of through go?

Answer (score 0):

I will do this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := "scp"
    args := []string{"-i", "dragonstone.pem", "<user>@ubuntu:<file location>", "."}
    if err := exec.Command(cmd, args...).Run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully.")
}
```