# How do I get results from Go exec.Command().Output() with commands that do not return immediately?

Tags: go

I am using the answer in [How do you get the output of a system command in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877045/how-do-you-get-the-output-of-a-system-command-in-go) for a command that does not return immediately. My results look like a race condition. Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    date, err := exec.Command("date").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", date)

    ping, err := exec.Command("fping", "10.10.18.2", "-C10", "-q", "-e").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("ping has %d bytes and value [%s]\n", len(ping), ping)
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./race
The date is Wed Dec  8 14:46:08 EST 2021

ping has 0 bytes and value []
```

Here is the output from the command line:

```
fping 10.10.18.2 -C10 -q -e
10.10.18.2 : 1.23 1.53 1.31 1.30 1.17 1.25 1.10 1.15 1.26 1.11
```

There is a pause after the output of the date command, but the result of the fping call is not included in the return value. Similar fping commands works great when I create a pipe to read from standard out and use cmd.Start() and cmd.Wait().

Comment: Does the command write that output to stderr instead of stdout?  Is the -q  (quiet) flag a problem?

Comment: It's surprising the result are different w/ Start, Wait and pipe because that's exactly what Output does.  Does fping change its output when stdout is a terminal?

Comment: The code that I saw for Output uses Run() instead of Start() and Wait().

Comment: Run is a helper method that calls Start and Wait. See [source here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/os/exec/exec.go;l=337).

Comment: Penélope Stevens is right. fping ip -C 2 -q writes its result to stderr.

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.CombinedOutput would be a drop-in replacement that *does* capture stderr, if you don't have to distinguish between stdout and stderr.