# Prepend to stdout for a subprocess's output

Tags: go

Is there a way to prepend to `stdout` of subprocesses? `stdout` is of type io.Writer and I understand that it is immutable.

One way I thought to show the pid in each log was to add a logrus hook to each of the subprocess. But still want to know if there is a way to modify the `stdout`.

This test runs 3 subprocesses and sends their `stdout` & `stderr` to first program's `stdout` and `stderr`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func Crasher(t *testing.T) {
    logrus.Info("huhaha")
    // This runs test with lots of logs.
}

func startProcess(pid int) {
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[0], "-test.run=^TestCrasher$")
    cmd.Env = append(os.Environ(), "BE_CRASHER=1")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    logrus.Infof("Starting process with pid %d", pid)
    _ = cmd.Run()
}

func TestCrasher(t *testing.T) {
    if os.Getenv("BE_CRASHER") == "1" {
        Crasher(t)
        return
    }

    for pid := 0; pid < 3; pid++ {
        go startProcess(pid)
    }
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestCrasher
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 0"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 2"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 1"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
PASS
PASS
PASS
--- PASS: TestCrasher (5.00s)
PASS
```

What I want:

```
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 0"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 2"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 1"
pid0 time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
pid1 time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
pid2 time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/fKkLGtcigtm

Comment: Why do you do `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout`? I believe you can read yourself the `cmd.stdout`, do with it whatever you want and only then print it

Comment: Yes. The question was out of curiosity to see if there is a faster way to do that, especially when the logs could come at a very high rate and if there is a way to just prepend something without reading the whole reader.

Comment: Checkout `cmd.Output()` or `cmd.CombinedOutput()` if you want to process the output as a whole (note that logrus default logs to `os.Stderr`. Or use `cmd.StderrPipe()` to pipe the output from the command. Further more you could implement your own `io.Writer` and assign that to the command. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877045/how-do-you-get-the-output-of-a-system-command-in-go

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want it to prepend smth to the output? May be what you want is to have `pid=id` string in the output?

It could be done by `logrus` without any hacking. Send child ID using environment or command line, and use [`Logger.WithFields`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus#Logger.WithFields) to add whatever fields you need to see in every line.

Example here: https://go.dev/play/p/M7wJ9VvlPOO
Output:

```
=== RUN   TestCrasher
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 2"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 1"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg="Starting process with pid 0"
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha pid=2
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=warning msg=foo-bla-blaaa pid=2
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha pid=1
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=warning msg=foo-bla-blaaa pid=1
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=info msg=huhaha pid=0
time="2009-11-10T23:00:00Z" level=warning msg=foo-bla-blaaa pid=0
PASS
PASS
PASS
--- PASS: TestCrasher (5.00s)
PASS
```

You can filter ouput per process by `pid=` string.

Comment: In the question, I did tell that I can use the logrus hook to do this, which is exactly what you are showing. My question is out of curiosity to see if is possible to manipulate io.Writer (stdout) somehow. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may set `cmd.Stdout / cmd.Stderr` to something else than `os.Stdout / os.Stderr` :

```
    // create a pipe to collect the output, and process it in a separate goroutine
    r, w := io.Pipe()

    // choose a way to signal this goroutine has completed
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        // choose whatever way you see fit to process the output:
        // for example, instanciate a Scanner and read output line by line
        s := bufio.NewScanner(r)
        for s.Scan() {
            // for some reason , the output contains garbled characters in the playground, haven't debugged why
            fmt.Printf("pid=%d %s\n", pid, s.Text())
        }
    }()

    // you can process just Stderr (log output) or both Stderr and Stdout
    cmd.Stdout = w
    cmd.Stderr = w
```

https://go.dev/play/p/zFsahhqjoIJ